# Not able to download Oracle's jdk-8u181 package using wget behind an HTTP proxy

Tags: oracle, java-8, wget, http-proxy

I'm trying to use WebUpd8 team's [`oracle-java8-installer`](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) to install Java 8 on my Ubuntu 14.04 computers. Some of them could succeed but others failed. After some debugging, I realized it was caused by the **HTTP proxy setting**. I'll provide more details below, but basically my questions are: **Why does the use of `http_proxy` cause the problem?** I believe it's must be related to how an HTTP proxy works, but since I have little experience in that, **could someone tell me what knowledge I should learn to understand this issue?**

Here are more details.

Under the hood, the `oracle-java8-installer` uses `wget` to download the jdk-8u181 package. So **I can reproduce** the issue with the steps below:

- Install `apt-cacher-ng`: `sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng`
- You don't have to configure anything in the APT configuration to reproduce this problem. `apt-cacher-ng` uses `localhost:3142` by default to cache the packages.
- Run `http_proxy="http://localhost:3142" wget --continue --no-check-certificate -O jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Here are some notes:

- The `http://localhost:3142` is configured for `apt-cacher-ng`. Those machines that failed had `apt-cacher-ng` installed before I tried to install jdk-8u181.
- The `Cookie: oraclelicense=a` is to indicate the user has accepted the license.

If you run the last command, the download of the `jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz` is finished instantly. There is a line saying "Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK". But if you open the received ".tar.gz", you'll see it's merely an HTML page that contains error information.

If you remove the `http_proxy` environment variable and run:

`wget --continue --no-check-certificate -O jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz`

You will have the full package downloaded correctly.

My best guess is that an HTTP proxy works with `wget` if the target URL is the final URL, so the proxy would cache it in its storage. Conceptually, it's like a key-value store:

```
proxy['URL'] = result
```

However, in this case, the target URL (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz) actually returns a ["302" code](https://httpstatuses.com/302) and a "Location" header field for the new URL. This can be seen from the output:

> ywen@ubuntu:~$ wget --continue --no-check-certificate -O
>   jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=a"
>   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
>   --2018-08-01 11:10:04--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.32.72.143
>
> Connecting to download.oracle.com
>   (download.oracle.com)|23.32.72.143|:80... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
>
> Location:
>   https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
>   [following]
>
> --2018-08-01 11:10:04--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)...
>   23.216.148.161, 2001:559:19:3081::2d3e, 2001:559:19:3086::2d3e
>
> Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com
>   (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.216.148.161|:443... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **302 Moved Temporarily**
>
> **Location:
>   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1533136324_72efc4e6208a5a7fc1cbba0527c741b6**
>   [following]
>
> --2018-08-01 11:10:04--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1533136324_72efc4e6208a5a7fc1cbba0527c741b6
>
> Connecting to download.oracle.com
>   (download.oracle.com)|23.32.72.143|:80... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>
> Length: 185646832 (177M) [application/x-gzip]
>
> Saving to: ‘jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz’

Handling the redirection is out of the capability of a proxy (Am I right??), therefore those machines set with the HTTP proxies failed.

Comment: Try asking your question at superuser.com.  SO is for programming questions.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Ah, that makes sense! I should have remembered Superuser. :-)